# Is it possible to lay out several choice options horizontally for one selection field in a display file?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to add a selection field to a display file using CHOICE DDS keyword. This selection field has three candidate values. By default all three options will be displayed in a single column. I want to lay them out horizontally on the same line. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

A menu bar will display options horizontally.  See the [`MNUBAR` DDS keyword](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakc%2Frzakcmstmnubar.htm).

This is a record level keyword, so you would need to define a record format specifically for this, which might not always be what you had in mind.

Comment: The display of MNUBAR is not really what I want so I prefer to stick with CHOICE. Does it mean that there is no way out of it? The options have to be laid out vertically?

Comment: You could always simply show a list of allowed values to the right, like the OS does when you prompt a CL command.

Comment: Or, if you are willing to make an entire display method paradigm shift you could investigate UIM, and try Panel Groups instead of Display Files.  Check out the [Application Display Programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzakc/sc415715.pdf) Manual, Parts 3, 5, and 6.  There *might* be a way to do it there, but I wouldn't count on it.  It would involve learning a new way to use displays, so it may not be for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 2):

If you need "selection choices" laid out horizontally, you have a variety of options. In increasing order of difficulty:

First, use a [SFLSNGCHC (Subfile Single Choice Selection List)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzakc/rzakcmstdfsng.htm) subfile. That's probably easiest, but there isn't much definition to go on here.

Next, use UIM. It's essentially a markup language related to HTML, so you might not find it difficult. The hardest part might be learning how to use the APIs and in coding any needed 'exit' functions. Knowing UIM can be worthwhile if you do a lot of green-screen display development.

Or use conditioning indicators. Line up a horizontal series of single-position input fields separated by output fields. Put variable text into the output fields as your options change. Condition however many of them you need across the line. Any fields on the right that aren't need can be DSPATR(PR ND).

Finally, use the [Dynamic Screen Manager (DSM) APIs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/dsm.htm) to make the screen work almost any way you choose. (This could also be done by a [USRDFN (User-Defined)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzakc/rzakcmstdfudfn.htm) record format.)